# How can I log into a simple web access login using Python?

Tags: python, web, browser, authentication, mechanize

I'm trying to create a little Python script that'll log into a web access authentication page for me automatically for the purposes of convenience (the login appears each time the computer is disconnected from the network).

[image: login]

My attempt so far has been to use the module mechanize, but running this doesn't result in the login vanishing from my standard browser:

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]
browser.open("https://controller.mobile.lan/101/portal/")
browser.select_form(name="logonForm")
browser["login"] = "myUsername"
browser["password"] = "myPasscode"
browser.submit()
print browser.title()
```

How can I get this login to work in Python?

Here's what I think is the relevant section of the HTML of the login page:

```
<form name="logonForm" style="display:none">
    <!-- Logon Form -->
    <div id="logonForm_subscriptionChoice_top_title_block" class="subtitle">
        <span id="logonForm_subscriptionChoice_top_title_text">YOU ALREADY HAVE YOUR LOGIN</span>
    </div>
    <div id="logonForm_auth_modes_block" style="display:none">
    <table class="hoverLink"><tr>
<td>
                <div id="logonForm_shibboleth_authentication_button">
                    <img src="./resources/_images/shibboleth.png" height="30px"><br><span id="logonForm_shibboleth_text">Utilisez vos identifiants institutionnels</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="logonForm_standard_authentication_button">
                    <img src="./resources/_images/ticket.png" height="30px"><br><span id="logonForm_ticket_text">Utilisez un ticket de connexion</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr></table>
</div>
    <div id="logonForm_logon_block">
        <table>
<tr id="logonForm_logon_block_credentials">
<td class="label">
                    <span id="logonForm_login_text">LOGIN</span><br><input type="text" name="login" autocomplete="on">
</td>
                <td class="label">
                    <span id="logonForm_password_text">PASSWORD</span><br><input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="on">
</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" id="logonForm_connect_button"><span><img src="./resources/_images/auth_button.png" height="35px"></span></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr id="logonForm_policy_block">
<!-- Check Box Confirm (Visible status depends on configuration option) --><td colspan="3">
                    <br><input type="checkbox" name="policy_accept">&nbsp;
                    <span id="logonForm_policy_text"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</div>
    <br><button type="button" id="logonForm_authentication_form_back_button" style="display:none">Retour</button>
    <div id="logonForm_subscriptionChoice_block">
        <br><div class="subtitle">
            <span id="logonForm_subcribe_bottom_title_text">NOT A LOGIN YET ?</span>
        </div>
        <br><div id="logonForm_subscriptionChoice_first_double_insert_block">
            <table class="hoverLink"><tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr></table>
</div>
        <div id="logonForm_subscriptionChoice_second_double_insert_block">
            <table class="hoverLink"><tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr></table>
</div>
        <div id="logonForm_subscriptionChoice_single_insert_block">
            <table class="hoverLink"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That form submits data somewhere. You need to find out where and what method it uses. After you find out, you can use the `requests` library to do a one-liner, like:

```
response = requests.post("https://controller.mobile.lan/101/portal/", data={'login': "username", 'password': "password")
print response.read() # Dumps the whole webpage after.
```

Note that if that form uses javascript for submission, mechanize won't do it and you'll have to get something that actually makes javascript tick. Mechanize's FAQ ([here](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html#general)) specifies that it doesn't do javascript and you have to emulate it in your own code.

Edit: If you have PyQt4 lying around, or can install it, you can use a 'headless' browser, like this:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication  
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

# Set vars here for convenience
username = "myUsername"
password = "myPassword"

class HeadlessBrowser(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        super(HeadlessBrowser, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.login)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_();

    def login(self):
        doc = self.mainFrame().documentElement()
        user = doc.findFirst("input[name=login]")
        pwd = doc.findFirst("input[name=password]")
        button = doc.findFirst("button[id=logonForm_connect_button]")

        user.setAttribute("value", username)
        pwd.setAttribute("value", password)
        button.evaluateJavaScript("this.click()")
        # Uncomment if the button click above is not enough
        #form = doc.findFirst("form[name=logonForm]")
        #form.evaluateJavaScript("this.submit()")
        self.app.quit()

page = HeadlessBrowser("http://localhost/~iskren/headlesstest.html")
html = page.mainFrame().toHtml()
```

And the contents of `http://localhost/~iskren/headlesstest.html` that I used for testing:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="logonForm"> 
        <input type="text" name="login"/>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
        <button type="submit" id="logonForm_connect_button">Click me!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes, I can see that mechanize would need additional custom code to work in this case (the page does use JavaScript). For now, I'm using the Python bindings of [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). This is intuitive, but inelegant (it loads up Firefox graphically etc. to do its thing).